# How to handle Series and Array with pandas and numpy together?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, series

I am new to Python and I am very confused with all these data type such as Series, Array, List etc.  Probably this is a very open ended question.  I am hoping to get a feel on the general practice when coding in python for data analysis.

Lots of readings have been suggesting that numpy and pandas are the two modules I needed for data analysis.  However, I find it hard and weird as they are operating/generating data in two different data types, i.e. Series and Array.  Is it normal/natural that one needs to convert either one of the data type to another one before any kind of data manipulation?  Would like you know what would you do?  Many thanks.

for example:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np

 # create some data
 df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
 x = np.random.randn(10, 1)

 # data manipulation
 A = df['a']

 # Question 1:
 # If I want to perform a element by element addition between x and A
 # How should I do?  Simple x + A doesn't work but it seems strange to 
 # me that if I have to convert the data type everytime 

 # Question 2:
 # I'd like to combine to two columns together
 # concatenate or hstack both don't work
```

Comment: What are you wanting to get `numpy.arrays` or `pd.Series` and `pd.Dataframes`?

Comment: I presume I would want dataframe at the end as I start with dataframe (since i import data using pandas).  Basically, I find them not compatible with each other (the two modules) which is annoying and wondering if i am in the right direction (require an extra step/function in almost each operation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it normal/natural that one needs to convert either one of the data
>   type to another one before any kind of data manipulation?

Sometimes you need to, sometimes you don't. When in doubt, do it.

That said, remember the Zen of Python:

- Explicit is better than implicit.
- In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.

Even if some APIs will do their best to convert types for you (numpy and pandas are quite good at that), explicit type casting can make your code more readable and easier to debug.

> Question 1:
>   If I want to perform a element by element addition between x and A How should I do?  Simple x + A doesn't work but it seems strange to me that if I have to convert the data type everytime

You do not have to convert data types in this case but you need compatible shapes.

```
>>> print(A.shape)
(10,)
>>> print(x.shape)
(10, 1)
>>> print(A + x.reshape(10))
0   -0.207131
1   -2.117012
2    0.925545
3   -2.187705
4    1.226458
5    2.144904
6   -0.956781
7    1.956246
8    0.060132
9    1.332417
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

> Question 2: I'd like to combine to two columns together concatenate or hstack both don't work

It is not clear what the desired output is but I think it is again a matter of shapes, not types. Here is an option the pandas way:

```
>>> print(pd.concat([A, pd.Series(x.reshape(10))], axis=1))
          a         0
0 -0.158667 -0.048463
1 -0.847246 -1.269765
2 -0.128232  1.053778
3 -1.316113 -0.871593
4  1.057044  0.169414
5  3.188343 -1.043439
6 -0.032524 -0.924257
7  1.412443  0.543803
8 -0.730386  0.790519
9  0.289796  1.042621
```

Answer (score 2):

For addition your `arrays`/`Series` should be with the same dimensions:

```
In [98]: A.shape
Out[98]: (10,)

In [99]: x.shape
Out[99]: (10, 1)
```

You could cast `reshape(-1)` to convert your vector to array:

```
In [100]: x.reshape(-1).shape
Out[100]: (10,)
```

Then you could add that with `pd.Series` A:

```
In [61]: A + x.reshape(-1)
Out[61]:
0   -1.186957
1   -0.165563
2    0.882490
3    4.544357
4    2.698414
5    0.396110
6   -0.199209
7    3.282942
8    2.448213
9   -0.543727
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

For your 2nd question you need to reshape your A `Series` for the vector. You could do it with `reshape`:

```
In [97]: np.hstack([A.values.reshape(A.size,1), x])
Out[97]:
array([[ 0.3158111 , -1.50276813],
       [-1.09532212,  0.92975954],
       [-0.77048623,  1.65297592],
       [ 2.14690242,  2.39745455],
       [ 1.63367806,  1.06473634],
       [ 0.09134512,  0.3047644 ],
       [ 0.02019805, -0.21940726],
       [ 0.87008192,  2.41286007],
       [ 1.25315724,  1.19505578],
       [-0.60156045,  0.05783343]])
```

If you want to get `pd.DataFrame` you could use `pd.concat`:

```
In [108]: pd.concat([A, pd.Series(x.reshape(-1))], axis=1)
Out[108]:
          a         0
0  0.315811 -1.502768
1 -1.095322  0.929760
2 -0.770486  1.652976
3  2.146902  2.397455
4  1.633678  1.064736
5  0.091345  0.304764
6  0.020198 -0.219407
7  0.870082  2.412860
8  1.253157  1.195056
9 -0.601560  0.057833
```

**EDIT**

From [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) for `reshape(-1)`:

> **newshape** : *int or tuple of ints*
>   The new shape should be compatible with the original shape. If an integer, then the result will be a 1-D array of that length. One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.

Comment: what does .reshape(-1) do/mean?  Thanks

Comment: Edited answer for that

Comment: @Lafayette note, that `reshape(-1)` will work for any shape of your original array while `reshape(10)` will be acceptable only for vector with 10 size.